# Office365 API - Pulling my userphoto

Tags: office365api

I have a simple web app that for the past month or so the following was working:

```
outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/userphotos('120x120')/$value
```

but now it returns:

```
{"error":{"code":"RequestBrokerOld-ParseUri","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'userphotos'."}}
```

I get the same error if I try any of the following:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/userphoto
https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/userphotos
https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/userphoto/$value
```

It is possible that my organisation has changed something to cause this? Or has there been a general change in how this request works?

In the same app, my other email and calendar requests all work fine, this is simply just a cosmetic problem of not displaying the users profile pic in the top corner.

Comment: I am getting same error.. Some of our prod apps using this.. So bad, MSFT does not have fallback :-(

Comment: The API endpoint has been changed to "photo". More information about this can be found here: http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-3-on-Office-365-unified-API

Comment: @ElioStruyf Great! this should be the correct answer: https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/photo/$value pulls down the photo correctly (I'm not sure about {size} flag of ('120x120') working, but that is no biggie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really [ElioStruyf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521186/elio-struyf)'s answer.

The endpoint is now called "photo" and not "userphoto"

To get the photo information you use:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/photo
```

To get the photo you call

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/photo/$value
```

To get list of all available photo sizes, use this API endpoint -

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/Photos/
```

Sample response -

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/$metadata#Me/Photos",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('48X48')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('48X48')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "48X48",
            "Height": 48,
            "Width": 48
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('64X64')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('64X64')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "64X64",
            "Height": 64,
            "Width": 64
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('96X96')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('96X96')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "96X96",
            "Height": 96,
            "Width": 96
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('120X120')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('120X120')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "120X120",
            "Height": 120,
            "Width": 120
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('240X240')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('240X240')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "240X240",
            "Height": 240,
            "Width": 240
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('360X360')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('360X360')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "360X360",
            "Height": 360,
            "Width": 360
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('432X432')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('432X432')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "432X432",
            "Height": 432,
            "Width": 432
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('504X504')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('504X504')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "504X504",
            "Height": 504,
            "Width": 504
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('648X648')",
            "@odata.readLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('John.Doe@contoso.com')/Photos('648X648')",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
            "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"7A1F3A9D\"",
            "Id": "648X648",
            "Height": 648,
            "Width": 648
        }
    ]
}
```

To fetch actual blob of desired photo size, call this API -

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/Photos('120X120')/$value
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate.. where did you find it?

Comment: @RahulPatil In the comments under the question Elio Struyf pointed me to: http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-3-on-Office-365-unified-API  ... I still haven't been able to get an image of a certain size (eg outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Me/photo('120x120')/$value) to work

Comment: Try this end point - https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users(user_email_id')/Photos('120X120')/$value

Comment: Or this end point.. simplified - https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/Photos('120X120')/$value

Comment: @RahulPatil Yes, "Photos" (with an 's' on the end) works. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's wrong with your organization's office 365 configuration. Outlook UserPhoto API has stopped working with the given endpoint. Unfortunately, they haven't updated the documentation yet. Let's hope it will be up soon or they will at least update documentation with new API endpoint.

Comment: Phew, its not just me. Thanks for letting me know. I'll be checking https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/photo-rest-operations to see if they do update their documentation. It is in beta, so they do warn that it may break, but it would be good if MS did tell us when it is broken