# Office 365 unified API error "Resource not found for the segment 'UserPhotos'."

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

A week or two ago, if a user had no photo the Office 365 unified API would return metadata for a photo of size 1X1. Now it's returning the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBrokerOld-ParseUri",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'UserPhotos'."
  }
}
```

Now the error has started to appear for users that do have photos. It's been getting progressively worse over the last few days, to the point that the API is unusable now. It started off as only a few missing photos, and now only 1 user photo is returned successfully out of over 250 users.

All [User Photo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/photo-rest-operations) endpoints are returning this error. E.g:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/userphotos
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/users/someUserId/userphotos/48X48
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/users/someUserId/userphoto/$value
```

The error is occuring in the [sandbox](https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/) too (although I can't be sure the user in the sandbox does have a photo to begin with).

Is there any known workaround or fix for this issue?

Comment: I asked this a few days ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406065/office365-api-pulling-my-userphoto Someone else has said it doesn't work for them either. I think the userphoto API is broken at the moment.

Comment: @Ampers I just found your question while searching for a workaround. Hopefully we get a fix soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some updates in the API:
http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-3-on-Office-365-unified-API
to get to the photo, please use /photo instead of /userPhoto

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406065/office365-api-pulling-my-userphoto):

The endpoint is now called "photo" and not "userphoto"

To get the photo information you use:

```
api/beta/Me/photo
```

To get the photo you call

```
api/beta/Me/photo/$value
```

I haven't been able to get photos for a given size (eg beta/Me/photo/48x48) to work